# How to include mysql.h in an OpenCV C++ Program?

Tags: c++, mysql, opencv, cmake

(Ubuntu 14.04) I currently have a OpenCV C++ program, which I am compiling and running by these commands (and it sure works):

`$cd release && cmake .. && make && cd bin && ./testProgram`

I have another C++ program to interact with the MySQL database, which I'm compiling using:

```
$c++ dbProgram.cpp `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

and it works fine!

Now, I want to interact with database from my OpenCV testProgram.cpp

I have made a change in the CMakeLists.txt file as follows:

```
set(CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS "`mysql_config --cflags --libs`")
```

Now, I run: 
`$cd release && cmake .. && make && cd bin && ./testProgram`
and I get errors saying:

```
c++ error: mysql_config: no such file or directory
c++ error: unrecognized command line option --cflags
c++ error: unrecognized command line option --libs
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(test)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(${FLAG_STRING} "`mysql_config --cflags --libs`")
set(GCC_CXX_FLAGS "${GCC_CXX_FLAGS} ${FLAG_STRING}")
add_executable(test testProgram.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

What do I do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your CMakeLists.txt to add mysql to your `target_link_libraries` and `include_directories`. Use a finder to get the paths.

Comment: ***mysql_config --cflags --libs*** CMake will not spawn an executable append to the CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS CMake variable. It will pass this directly to g++ so you get the error.

Comment: What changes should I make exactly? and get the paths of what?

Comment: ***and get the paths of what?*** to get the path of the libraries and headers of the client mysql library in CMake variables. ***What changes should I make exactly?*** I did not answer the question because I do not use mysql with CMake. I do use CMake daily for 8 years however so I expect mysql to not be that different from most other packages.